# Как реализовать щипок для масштабирования?

Tags: android

Как на андройде реализован `щипок` двумя пальцами для масштабирования?
Есть ли отдельное событие?

Comment: Есть [замечательная библиотека SimpleFingerGestures](https://github.com/championswimmer/SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library?utm_source=androiddevdigest) по детектированию  жестов, в том числе и "щипка" (pinch/unpinch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pinchTitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pinch_title" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pinchTitleText"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/zoom"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class PinchZoomActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView imageView;
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));
        matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Для масштабирования именно картинки лучше показывать ее в `WebView`, лайфхак старый, но вроде рабочий. Зум должен быть по дефолту. На крайняк вот вам либы

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView
https://github.com/ongakuer/PhotoDraweeView

Если грузите картинки через `Fresko` то юзайте вторую

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, самый простой способ - скопировать этот класс, расширяюший `ImageView`:
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

В коде файла разметки `xml` напишИте:

```
<_имя_вашего_пакета_.TouchImageView/>
```

Удачи!